# The "command-line" tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I'm very keen on the [command-line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/command-line) tag, so I've decided to edit [it's tag wiki](https://askubuntu.com/tags/command-line/info).

I've tried to give a gentle definition of the term, without sounding condescending to those who know about the command line already. I've also tried to provide helpful links.

Have I done it right? Are you happy with what I've come up with, or am i going in the wrong direction altogether?

Aside from this: I think the Excerpt might be a bit too basic. I'd be thankful if somebody has a better idea for what to put in it. As I've said, this tag is important to me.

Comment: Great job, especially the cute icon on the official documentation.

Comment: Awesome :) now I just need 5 more characters to compliment with you :P

Comment: Just did my first tag wiki and after reading meta questions regarding plagarism and then reading this meta question and your command-line wiki  now have an ideal example of how a tag wiki should look like. Thank you.